# get value from array of string in datagridview and do calculation

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have dgv which contains table like follow that check number of item. And now I need to calculate average after key in data.

| ID | Part No | Item 1 | Item 2 | Item 3 | Average |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P01 | Top | 11 | 14 | 12 | 12.3 |
| P02 | Middle | 12 | 15 | 11 | 12 |
| P03 | Bottom | 10 | 13 | 16 | 13 |

I have create coding like this and it shows no error.

```
For Each c As DataColumn In dgv1.Columns
                Dim j, sum As Integer
                If dgv1.Rows(0).Item(c).Contains(Data & "" & (j)) Then
                    For i = 0 To dgv1.Rows.Count - 1
                        Try
                            sum += Convert.ToInt32(dgv1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value)
                        Catch ex As Exception

                        End Try
                    Next
                    dgv1.Item("Average", curRow).Value = sum / (j)
                End If
            Next
```

But when run the system, it stated unable to cast object of type 'system.windows.form.datagridviewtextboxcolumn' to type 'system.data.datacolumn'
what does it mean because if i use datagridviewcolumn for datacolumn also cannot run. I am very new on VB.net and I need someone help on this.Is there a better way or reference for this? Thanks

Comment: First things first, turn `Option Strict On` in the project properties and start writing your code properly, respecting data types. You should also turn it `On` in the VS options, so it is `On` by default in future versions.

Comment: Why would you expect anything different? Exactly as the error message says, the `Long` data type has no `Contains` method. That might be a reasonable thing to do if you were checking whether a `String` contained a substring but three of your columns contain numbers so what exactly is that `Contains` method supposed to be accomplishing?

Comment: `DataColumn` is the Type of Columns in a DataTable, not in the DataGridView. + Your loop is inverted + `Integer` won't give you floating point values - if you actually want to use floating point values, as the first *sample result* would suggest, while the sample that follows doesn't. -- `j` is never incremented, you probably meant to use `i`. -- You need to be very specific, describe the Data Type of the Columns of your DataTable. -- As suggested, `Option Strict On` before anything else.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the `DataTable`’s [ExpressionColumn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=net-5.0) … Creating an expression column will do all the work for you and render your code unnecessary.

Comment: `dgv1.Rows(0).Item` `Item` is not a member of a `DataGridViewRow`

Comment: Where did the data in the grid come from? Is it bound to a DataTable?

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear how the “average” column is inserted into the grid. I would assume that the “Average” column is NOT getting returned from the DB and is added by your code.

In that case a simple solution is to add the “Average” column to the `DataTable` returned from the DB. Then set that columns “Expression” `string` to calculate the average you are wanting.

To show a full example of this, I will assume that when the code gets the data from the data base, that it returns a `DataTable.` If this is the case then all we need to do is add the “expression” column to that `DataTable.` Adding the “expression” column to the `DataTable` may look something like...

```
Private Sub AddExpressionColumn(GridTable As DataTable)
  Dim col = New DataColumn("Average")
  col.DataType = GetType(Decimal)
  col.Expression = "(Item1 + Item2 + Item3) / 3"
  GridTable.Columns.Add(col)
End Sub
```

Above, the code takes a `DataTable` with existing columns named “Item1”, “Item2” and “Item3” and adds those column values together then divides by three (3). Now, if the user “changes” one of the “Item” values, then, the “Average” value will update automatically.

To show a full example, create a new VB winforms project, drop a `DataGridView` onto the form, and finally paste the code below to see this in action. The picture below shows the added “Average” column in light green.

[image]

```
Dim rand As Random = New Random()

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  Dim GridTable As DataTable = GetDataFromDB()
  AddExpressionColumn(GridTable)
  dataGridView1.DataSource = GridTable
  dataGridView1.Columns("Average").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "0.0"
End Sub

Private Sub AddExpressionColumn(GridTable As DataTable)
  Dim col = New DataColumn("Average")
  col.DataType = GetType(Decimal)
  col.Expression = "(Item1 + Item2 + Item3) / 3"
  GridTable.Columns.Add(col)
End Sub

Private Function GetDataFromDB() As DataTable
  Dim dt = New DataTable()
  dt.Columns.Add("ID", GetType(String))
  dt.Columns.Add("Part No.", GetType(String))
  dt.Columns.Add("Item1", GetType(Int32))
  dt.Columns.Add("Item2", GetType(Int32))
  dt.Columns.Add("Item3", GetType(Int32))
  dt.Rows.Add("PO1", "Top", 11, 14, 12)
  dt.Rows.Add("PO2", "Middle", 12, 15, 11)
  dt.Rows.Add("PO3", "Bottom", 10, 13, 16)
  For i = 4 To 10
    dt.Rows.Add("PO" + i.ToString(), "Part" + i.ToString(), rand.Next(1, 50), rand.Next(1, 50), rand.Next(1, 50))
  Next
  Return dt
End Function
```

I hope this makes sense and helps.

Answer (score 0):

Why make it so complicated.

```
For i = 0 To dgv1.Rows.Count - 1
  Dim Total as decimal = 0
  for x = 3 to dgv1.Columns.Count - 2
     Total =  Total + val(dgv1(x,i).Value)
  Next
     Dim j as integer = dgv1.Columns.Count - 3
     dgv1.Item("Average", i).Value = Total/j
Next
```

Do test it and let me know the result